# Running command in container shell raw vs command using /bin/bash -ac ,gettingdifferent results

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker

When doing `docker exec -it [container_id] /bin/bash`:

I ran the following:
Assume folder `test/data` exist.

```bsh
for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://foo-bucket | awk '{print $NF}'); do
    aws s3 cp foo-bucket/${file} test/data && tar -xzf test/data/${file} -C test/data/
done
```

For this I get all the files under the relevant path and extracted.  However when doing exactly the same via shell in this manner:

```bsh
/bin/bash -ac "for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://foo-bucket | awk '{print $NF}') ; do aws s3 cp foo-bucket/${file} test/data && tar -xzf test/data/${file} -C test/data/ ; done"
```

I get weird error such as:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token foo1.tar.gz'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: foo1.tar.gz ; do aws s3 cp s3://foo-bucket/foo1.tar.gz  test/data' && tar -xzf 'test/data/foo1.tar.gz' -C 'test/data/' ; done'
```

Any idea why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly the same! Look at the awk, in one you have

```
 awk '{print $NF}'
```

and in the other you have

```
 bash -c " .... awk '{print $NF}' ..."
```

In the first the `$` is protected by the single quotes, so the program for awk is `{print $NF}`, but the single quotes have no meaning in the second whilst the string is being constructed. Assuming you don't have a shell variable called `NF` defined, the latter gives

```
 bash -c " ... awk '{print }' ..."
```

so awk prints all of the output of your `aws` command, and the shell gives you syntax errors.

The $( ... ) is probably being evaluated at the wrong time as well.

In general always use single quotes rather than double quotes unless you **want** variables to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks now command works, but inside makefile in the same exact way no, do you have more information on how to make it work under `makefile `?

Comment: Makefile is yet another can of worms. First thing to do is change every `$` to `$$`.

Comment: yes tried that with no much success, anyway when saying about `Makefile`- can of worms - do you think that `Makefile` isn't recommanded for usage? Is there some `Makefile` linter that can help convert `bash` to `Makefile` form

Comment: Ask another question for the Makefile version. Put in what you already have, throw in an @icarus so I notice and I will try and help if no one else gets there first.